# Thermodynamics (Pressure-Temperature) Graph Analysis

Tags: thermodynamics

I am studying the Graphs in Thermodynamics, and I have found one graph that had made me very curious to know the Real concept of that. Please see it (below here) -

[image: It is a Pressure (on Y-axis) VS Volume (on X-axis) graph.]

So, here The *Line with* **Negative Slope** is the Main, which we have to analyze. So, here the **Volume** is constantly **Increasing** . So, my question is that," What is the Slope of this line AB is telling us ? For, example the Slope of the lines that are drawn dotted(in Yellow color), are telling us the variation of Volume ( acc. to the *Ideal Gas Equation* **P = nRT/V**, compare it with Straight line Equation, y = mx + c). So, We can see the **Slope of AB is also constant**, but its **Volume is Increasing**, so What it tells us? Is the **Slope of AB** is trying to tell something else, or I am missing out something. Please Help, its a genuine question.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you are missing the core idea of *Gay-Lussac's Law*, which says: If $V=\text{constant}$, then $P\propto T$, and converse is also true. See the dotted lines here are called *isochore lines* or simply *isochores*. if we have to write equations of lines we do following substitution: $x \rightarrow T, y\rightarrow P$

Now an isochore line has following equation: $P=mT$, where m is slope, or we can write: $P=\frac{P_1}{T_1}T$. In the previous equation we can clearly see that $P\propto T$, so the line/process is an isochoric process and $V$ is constant. Let us make the equation of process/line AB:

$$P-P_A=\frac{P_B-P_A}{T_B-T_A}(T-T_A)$$
$$P=\frac{P_B-P_A}{T_B-T_A}(T-T_A)+P_A$$

, clearly, the $P$ is NOT directly proportional to $T$. So the line/process AB is definitely, not an isochoric process/line.Further we can substitute: $V=nRT/P$, to get graph of V vs T, and see the variation (I guess calculations yield a downward curve parabola).